# How to convert class into generic type

Tags: c#, templates, generics, asp.net-web-api, types

I have a method to call api service to get some result and the return type of a method is a class type. For a single class I can able to specify name as its return type and its working fine. But in some cases the return type will get changed. In that scenario i got stuck in continuing the code. Please guide me on how can i achieve this one.

Expected Solution:
I expect to add the if condition in GetDoc(..) method in Details class. Based on docType, I need to changes the GetRequest(Records) into GetRequest(Employee).

```
public Class Details{
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDoc(string docType){

var result= await _apiService.GetRequest<Records>(  //in some cases i need to change 'Records' to 'Employee'
url,//api url
...
)

}
}
----------
public class Record{
public Record(int id, string name){
ID=id;
Name=name
}
public int ID{get; set;}
public string Name{get;set;
}

public class Employee{
public Record(int id, string name){
ID=id;
Name=name
}
public int ID{get; set;}
public string Name{get;set;
}

public class ApiService{

public async Task<IactionResult> GetRequest<T>(string url, ....){
// here i am deserializing the response content using jsonconvert.
}

}
```

Comment: You can use `if...else` based on the `docType` value...

Comment: What about `public async Task<IActionResult> GetDoc<T>(string docType)` with `_apiService.GetRequest<T>(...`

Comment: For example only i have given, Record and Employee.. But it can be 5 difference class.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I am calling thin Details class from type script. Is that possible to have GetDoc<T> ?. I didn't try like this yet. I will try this one. Thanks

Comment: @shobia I do believe a `switch` statement is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing it like the way you are approaching, I recommend creating different endpoints for each (I'm suggesting this because it looks like this is an endpoint to get details for varies entities). So, something like:

```
public class RecordController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int id)
    {
        var result = await _apiService.GetRequest<Record>(id);
        // Rest of the processing...
    }
}
```

Then another controller for employees:

```
public class EmployeeController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int id)
    {
        var result = await _apiService.GetRequest<Employee>(id);
        // Rest of the processing...
    }
}
```

If the rest of the logic allows it, you can go further and create a generic controller like:

```
public abstract class MyBaseController<T>
{
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int id)
    {
        var result = await _apiService.GetRequest<T>(id);
        // Rest of the processing...
        // If the processing is not generic you may be able to use a delegate to handle that bit.
    }
}
```

Now in your individual controllers, you can inherit like:

```
public class RecordController : MyBaseController<Record>
{
}
```

and

```
public class EmployeeController : MyBaseController<Employee>
{
}
```

Didn't actually test this. Just sketched the code to give you and idea to design the classes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.